# Directional derivative of a function $f(x,y)$ but direction in terms of $u$ and $v$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, implicit-function-theorem, multivalued-functions

I've been trying to solve this problem but I can't find the solution to it. The problem is as follows,

> Calculate the directional derivative of the function:
>   $$ f(x,y) = 3xy^2+2x^2-5x $$
>   as function of the variables $u$ and $v$:
>   \begin{align}
> u&=3x^3y+5y^2+2\\
> v&=-4-2yx^2+3y
> \end{align}
>   in the point $$P(x,y)=(-1,2)$$ and the direction of the vector $$w(u,v)=(3,-4)$$

If you could help me I'd appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried or where are you stuck? Please don't say you're stuck with everything. Surely you can look up the definition of directional derivative and start tinkering around with it.

Comment: @AlvinLepik I know what directional derivatives are, I don't know how can I find either the gradient of $f(x,y)$ in terms of $u\, and\, v$ or the vector $w(u,v)$ in terms of $x\, and\, y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic thing you need is $f_u$ and $f_v.$ I'll describe how to get the first. The second is like unto it.

So, we have that $$f_u=\frac{f_x}{u_x}+\frac{f_y}{u_y}.$$ Similarly, obtain $f_v.$ Then the gradient is $(f_u,f_v).$ Thus, at the point $(x,y)=(-1,2),$ the gradient is given by $\nabla_{(-1,2)}=(f_u(-1,2),f_v(-1,2)),$ so that in the direction $(3,-4),$ the derivative is given by the dot product of the unit vector $$\frac15(3,-4)$$ and $$\nabla_{(-1,2)}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I get it now.